# How to convert string to array in PHP for array_unique

Tags: php, sql

How can I convert my values string from MYSQL in array? So I can use array_unique. Because I have multiple duplicate in one column. And when I echo it out. It is displaying all in PHP. I tried DISTINCT but it just return only one column and not return other columns.

[image]
Keeps repeating the name (BOLD RED).

Code:

```
$querysql= "SELECT * FROM `stock` WHERE ID = '$id' ";

$fetchdata = $database->query($querysql);

while($rows= $fetchdata->fetch_assoc()) {

echo "<div id='companylocal'>";
    echo $rows['Company_Locate'];
echo "</div>";
}
```

Comment: would you please update your question with the current outputand what is your desired output because i m little bit confused with your question

Comment: @BunkerBoy added an image. And if you check it. It keeps repeating that's why it's not align very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
$querysql= "SELECT * FROM `stock` WHERE ID = '$id' ";

$fetchdata = $database->query($querysql);

while($row= $fetchdata->fetch_assoc()) {
    $rows[] = $row['Company_Locate'];
}
$rows = array_unique($rows);
print_r($rows);
```

Comment: It's working but why is there Array ( [0] => YoProgram Inst. [1] => ) Array (  YoProgram Inst. [2] => )

Comment: It's a way to print the array content. If you want to traverse one by one use foreach($rows as $v){echo $v;}

Answer (score 0):

Try using GROUP BY in your query

```
$querysql= "SELECT * FROM `stock` WHERE ID = '$id' GROUP BY Company_Locate";
```

Comment: I tried it but it's not working. It's just displaying the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Table Name: **Test**

---

|    **id**    |     **colA**     |      **colB**       |

---

|     5      |    value 5     |   value C   |

---

|     4      |    value 4     |   value B   |

---

|     3      |    value 3     |   value B   |

---

|     2      |    value 2     |   value B   |

---

|     1      |    value 1     |   value A   |

---

From my sample above. 
column(colA) has unique values while column(colB) has duplicates.
Grouping the query by column(colB) will return rows with unique values from column(colB)

SQL: *SELECT id, colA, colB FROM test GROUP BY colB*
Returns:

---

|    **id**    |     **colA**     |      **colB**       |

---

|     1      |    value 1     |   value A   |

---

|     2      |    value 2     |   value B   |

---

|     5      |    value 5     |   value C   |

---

for more better explanation please check https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

```
$DataFromDatabase = [ ['id' => 1,
                   'colA' => "value 1",
                   'colB' => "value A"
                  ],
                  ['id' => 2,
                   'colA' => "value 2",
                   'colB' => "value B"
                  ],
                  ['id' => 3,
                   'colA' => "value 3",
                   'colB' => "value B"
                  ],
                  ['id' => 4,
                   'colA' => "value 4",
                   'colB' => "value B"
                  ],
                  ['id' => 5,
                   'colA' => "value 5",
                   'colB' => "value C"
                  ]
                ];
    echo "Data FROM database<br/>";
```

`echo "<pre>";
print_r($DataFromDatabase);
echo "</pre>";`

`//Unique Array
$UniqueArray = [];`

```
//Loop the Database result
foreach($DataFromDatabase AS $data){
    //Make the unique value your key for your array
    $UniqueArray[$data['colB']][] = ['id' => $data['id'],
                                     'colA' => $data['colA']
                                    ];
}

echo "Unique Array<br/>";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($UniqueArray);
echo "</pre>";
```

The result of your uniqueArray will be
something like this:

```
Array
(
    [value A] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [colA] => value 1
                )

        )

    [value B] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [colA] => value 2
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [colA] => value 3
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [colA] => value 4
                )

        )

    [value C] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 5
                    [colA] => value 5
                )

        )

)
```

Values are stacked on each unique column(colB) values.
It's now up to you on how you are going to print the values of your array

Comment: Good example. Let's say I want to display id's 4 and 3 also and in your example they have duplicates in ColB. But if you GROUP BY in ColB, They will not show. So I just found a way which is unique_array in PHP. But I have strings and I dont know how to execute.

Comment: Hi @MonPadi I updated my answer. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Check my image bro. Thank you for helping me out so far.